# CurrencySymbol Delante de número siempre

Tags: java, android

tengo una duda con respecto a esta función, y pues resulta que en mi emulador el símbolo que definí aparece delante de los números pero al instalarlo en mi celular aparece al final de este.

Siendo que en emulador figura así: **S/.** 1,250.00

Y en mi celular se ve de este modo: 1,250.00 **S/.**

Entiendo que por el tipo de país este formato cambiará pero me gustaría tenerlo estático delante del número, actualmente solo le agregué el símbolo delante del "setText", pero me parecio buena idea preguntar también:

```
    public String getPromedio() {

    double valuea, valueb, valuec, valued, valuee;
    valuea = Double.parseDouble(periodo1);
    valueb = Double.parseDouble(periodo2);
    valuec = Double.parseDouble(periodo3);
    valued = Double.parseDouble(periodo4);
    valuee = (valuea + valueb + valuec + valued) / 4;
    NumberFormat pen_promedio = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    dfs.setCurrencySymbol("");
    ((DecimalFormat) pen_promedio).setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);

    promedio = pen_promedio.format(valuee);

    return promedio;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes definir un [Locale](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale) definiendo el código del pais, por ejemplo:

```
   //NumberFormat pen_promedio = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
   NumberFormat pen_promedio = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRENCH);
```

Por ejemplo si defines `Locale.US` obtienes:

```
S/.  1250,00
```

pero si defines `Locale.FRENCH` siempre obtendrás:

```
1.250,00 S/.
```

---

Otra opción es no definir un símbolo pero tu agregarlo delante del valor:

```
 dfs.setCurrencySymbol("");
 ...
 ...
 promedio = pen_promedio.format(valuee + " S/.");
```

Comment: en mi caso sería PEN y sale siempre al final por lo cual no me resulta conveniente, lo puse concatenando en el textview nada más

Comment: Si, creo que sería la opción más viable ya lo que deseas se logra pero usando un Locale que no es de nuestro continente americano hehe! :-)